# Google Sheets: Map GOOGLEFINANCE function over input range

Tags: google-sheets

tl;dr `=ARRAYFORMULA(GOOGLEFINANCE({"AAPL"; "GOOG"}; "price"))` returns a single row and not two. What am I doing wrong?

---

I'm trying to build a portfolio tracker in google sheets. I keep a trading history that tracks buys and sells, from which I derive the current portfolio.

[image: Trading History]

I'd also like to calculate portfolio value at certain points in the past to visualize growth. As part of this exercise I `FILTER`ed the trading history by date, and `INDEX`ed just the ticker symbols:

[image: Filtered History]

This formula returns an array - now I want to run `GOOGLEFINANCE` over each of these cells to get the closing price at the date specified and this is where I am stuck. Simply wrapping this range in a `GOOGLEFINANCE` does not work as it will return only one cell, in this case, the price of AAPL:

[image: GOOGLEFINANCE over input range]

Essentially I'm looking for some sort of map/reduce functionality. I have heard that `ARRAYFUNCTION` sort of does that but thruthfully I don't understand how it works and at least it seems like it doesn't do what I expect it to.

Temporary tables would of course do the trick but I would like to keep those to a minimum and just do everything in one massive formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GOOGLEFINANCE` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`. however, you can build an array like this:

```
={GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL"); 
  GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG")}
```

[image]

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks!